# how to grep date with format [EXISTS]: [TIMESTAMP] 10-26-2022_09-17-41-UTC?

Tags: bash, shell

`[EXISTS]:      [TIMESTAMP] 10-26-2022_09-17-41-UTC [SIZE]  ==>` have to `grep` such dates to further filter.

```
grep `date +"%m-%d-20%y"` sorted.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I have this (only the timestamp):

```
grep "[0-9]*\-[0-9]*\-[0-9]*_[0-9]*\-[0-9]*\-[0-9]*\-UTC" test.txt
```